# Why can't My GUI program built by PyQt5 show?

Tags: python, pyqt5

I refer to the article[1](https://www.wongwonggoods.com/python/pyqt5-15/) to build my GUI by PyQt5,The difference between the program of the article and mine is the module <img_controller.py>. When I initilize my img_controller instance,I only need the parameter ui(the class I got from Qtdesigner)and my program ,img_controller. will revise the attributes of ui. Initialize the parameters of img_controller.py according to [1](https://www.wongwonggoods.com/python/pyqt5-15/) are directed inputted  attributes of ui.

When I run the program got from [1](https://www.wongwonggoods.com/python/pyqt5-15/), it can work normally; but I run my program, I can't get the mainwindow and the wrong message hints that "AttributeError: 'Img_controller' object has no attribute 'ui'".I don't know where is my problem, because in the function __ init __ of Img_controller(class), I state that "self.ui = ui",anyone can tell me the problem, thank you very much.

The following is my program:

UI.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(1085, 857)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.verticalLayoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 20, 861, 491))
        self.verticalLayoutWidget.setObjectName("verticalLayoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.scrollArea = QtWidgets.QScrollArea(self.verticalLayoutWidget)
        self.scrollArea.setWidgetResizable(True)
        self.scrollArea.setObjectName("scrollArea")
        # self.scrollAreaWidgetContents = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        # self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 857, 487))
        # self.scrollAreaWidgetContents.setObjectName("scrollAreaWidgetContents")
        self.image_label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.scrollArea) #此處有更動
        self.image_label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 841, 471))
        self.image_label.setObjectName("image_label")
        self.scrollArea.setWidget(self.image_label) #此處有更動
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.scrollArea)
        self.btn_zoomin = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_zoomin.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(330, 530, 75, 23))
        self.btn_zoomin.setObjectName("btn_zoomin")
        self.btn_zoomout = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_zoomout.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(640, 530, 75, 23))
        self.btn_zoomout.setObjectName("btn_zoomout")
        self.slider = QtWidgets.QSlider(self.centralwidget)
        self.slider.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(440, 530, 160, 22))
        self.slider.setOrientation(QtCore.Qt.Horizontal)
        self.slider.setObjectName("slider")
        self.btn_open = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.btn_open.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 530, 75, 23))
        self.btn_open.setObjectName("btn_open")
        self.label_resolution = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_resolution.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(770, 530, 75, 15))
        self.label_resolution.setObjectName("label_resolution")
        self.label_filename = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_filename.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(130, 660, 111, 41))
        self.label_filename.setObjectName("label_filename")
        self.label_img_shape = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_img_shape.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(540, 620, 411, 51))
        self.label_img_shape.setObjectName("label_img_shape")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 1085, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.image_label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "image"))
        self.btn_zoomin.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "zoom_in"))
        self.btn_zoomout.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "zoom_out"))
        self.btn_open.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "open file"))
        self.label_resolution.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
        self.label_filename.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "file_name"))
        self.label_img_shape.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "TextLabel"))
```

img_controller.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
import cv2
from UI import Ui_MainWindow

class Img_controller(object):
    def __init__(self, ui:Ui_MainWindow, img_ratio:int = 50):
        super(Img_controller, self).__init__()
        self.img_path = 'sad.jpg'
        self.img_ratio = img_ratio
        self.read_img(self.img_path)
        self.ui = ui

    def read_img(self,img_path):
        try:
            self.img = cv2.imread(img_path)
            self.orig_h, self.orig_w, self.orig_c = self.img.shape
            self.img_path = img_path
        except:
            self.img = cv2.imread(self.img_path)
            self.orig_h, self.orig_w, self.orig_c = self.img.shape
        
        bytesPerline = self.orig_h*self.orig_c
        self.qimg = QtGui.QImage(self.img, self.orig_w, self.orig_h, bytesPerline, QtGui.QImage.Format_RGB888).rgbSwapped()
        self.origin_qpixmap = QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(self.qimg)
        self.img_ratio = 50        
        self.set_img_ratio()

    def set_img_ratio(self):
        self.img_ratio = pow(10, (self.img_ratio - 50)/50)
        qpixmap_height = self.orig_h * self.img_ratio
        self.qpixmap = self.origin_qpixmap.scaledToHeight(qpixmap_height)
        #更新UI介面上的顯示
        self.__update_img()
        self.__update_text_ratio()
        self.__update_text_img_shape()
        self.__update_text_file_path()

    def __update_img(self):
        self.ui.image_label.setPixmap(self.qpixmap)
        self.ui.image_label.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignLeft | QtCore.Qt.AlignTop)

    def __update_text_file_path(self):
        self.ui.label_filename.setText(f"File path = {self.img_path}")

    def __update_text_ratio(self):
        self.ui.label_resolution.setText(f"{int(100*self.img_ratio)} %")

    def __update_text_img_shape(self):
        current_text = f"Current img shape = ({self.qpixmap.width()}, {self.qpixmap.height()})"
        origin_text = f"Origin img shape = ({self.origin_width}, {self.origin_height})"
        self.ui.label_img_shape.setText(current_text+"\t"+origin_text)

    def set_zoom_in(self):
        self.img_ratio = max(0, self.img_ratio - 1)
        self.set_img_ratio()

    def set_zoom_out(self):
        self.img_ratio = min(100, self.img_ratio + 1)
        self.set_img_ratio()

    def set_slider_value(self, value):
        self.img_ratio = value
        self.set_img_ratio()
```

controller.py

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore,QtWidgets,QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QFileDialog
from img_controller import Img_controller
from UI import Ui_MainWindow

class Ui_controller(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Ui_controller,self).__init__()
        self.ui = Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self)
        self.setup_control()

    def setup_control(self):
        self.img_controller = Img_controller(ui = self.ui)

        self.ui.btn_open.clicked.connect(self.open_file)         
        self.ui.btn_zoomin.clicked.connect(self.img_controller.set_zoom_in)
        self.ui.btn_zoomout.clicked.connect(self.img_controller.set_zoom_out)
        self.ui.slider.valueChanged.connect(self.getslidervalue)


    def open_file(self):
        filename, filetype = QFileDialog.getOpenFileName(self, "Open file", "./") # start path        
        self.init_new_picture(filename)

    def init_new_picture(self, filename):
        self.ui.slider.setProperty("value", 50)
        self.img_controller.read_img(filename)        

    def getslidervalue(self):        
        self.img_controller.set_slider_value(self.ui.slider.value()+1)
```

Answer (score 0):

What you DIDN'T say was the key piece of information -- the rest of the traceback.  Notice that `Img_controller.__init__` calls `self.read_img`, which calls `self.set_img_ratio`, which calls `self.__update_img`, which uses `self.ui`, and that all happens BEFORE you set `self.ui`.  You need to swap the order of that initialization.